# Why in React map returns element <li> and index in tree DOM?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

This is my first question. Thank you for your understanding and help.
This is my code:

```
 Object.entries(category[1]).map(group => (
   Object.entries(group[1].sort().map((product, index) => (
     <li key={product.id}
         className="products-wrapper__item">
           <h1>{`product-${index}`}</h1>
     </li>
    )
   ))
 ))
```

Why this code before list item get index number?
This code returns:
[http://i.imgur.com/88QtjmG.pnghttp://i.imgur.com/88QtjmG.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coUiS.png)

Comment: You probably want `Object.values`. However, also note that `sort()` sorts the array in place. That means you are probably modifying your state/props from `render` and that's very bad.